# How to delete cache using javascript in Pale Moon browser?

Tags: javascript, palemoon

I want to delete the cache and cookies on Pale Moon browser but I don't know to do it.
In Firefox I use this code:

```js
function clearFirefox () {
  //Clear cookies
  Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"]
  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieManager).removeAll();
 
  //Clear cache
  Components.classes["@mozilla.org/netwerk/cache-storage-service;1"]
  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsICacheStorageService).clear();
  Components.classes["@mozilla.org/netwerk/cache-storage-service;1"]
  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsICacheStorageService).purgeFromMemory(3);
}
```

Comment: Have you read the API docs for the Pale Moon browser (if there are any)?

Comment: I didn't read it because is the first time when I use it and I really don't know nothing about it. I use Pale Moon because I use iMacros on it and I really need to clear cache and cookies.

Comment: I'd ask the creators of the browser. It's not really something people "just know".

Comment: So, do I have any chances to find how to delete cache and cookies using .js?